# View the history of the Visual Studio status bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

When I add a reference to my web project I end up with an older version dll than expected (issue besides the point).

**Visual Studio** shows *"Adding path etc..."*, but sometimes you have too little time to read that, and then the status changes to something like *"Reference added ok"*.

Now, had I been able to read that path in the status, I would have solved that issue a lot faster.

So, back to the question: **Is there a way to view the status history after a command in VS has been completed?**

Thanks!

*PS I actually got to read what was going on in the status bar by filming it with my phone and looking at the right frame in the video. Whatever works, you know! :)*